# django sets empty value to excluded model fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Some of the model field are excluded in the django form. when I use `form.save()`, the existing values of these fields are automatically replaced by empty string.

But according to django doc:

"Any fields not included in a form by the above logic will not be set by the form’s save() method"

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my form and model:

```
class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'First Name'
        })
    )
    last_name = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Last name'
        })
    )
    division = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=True,
        choices=[(x, x) for x in range(1, 32)],
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )
    city = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=True,
        choices=[(x, x) for x in range(1, 32)],
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )
    thana = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=True,
        choices=[(x, x) for x in range(1, 32)],
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )
    national_id = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'National ID'
        })
    )
    passport_number = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Passport No'
        })
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        exclude = ['user', 'activated', 'activation_key', 'slug', 'created']
        # fields = ('username', 'email',)
        # fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'division', 'city', 'thana', 'national_id', 'passport_number')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        print("in save!")
        profile = super(ProfileEditForm, self).save(commit=False)
        profile.activated = True
        print(str(profile.activation_key))
        if commit:
            profile.save()
        return profile
```

model

```
User = get_user_model()

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True) # user.profile
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    division = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    thana = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    national_id = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    passport_number = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null= True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=200, null= True, blank= True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


def post_save_user_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    print("In rl_post _save" + str(instance.slug) + str(instance.activation_key) + str(instance.activated))
    if created:
        profile, is_created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(post_save_user_receiver, sender=Profile, dispatch_uid="rl_pre_save_receiver")

def rl_pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    # instance.category = instance.category.capitalize()
    print("In rl_pre _save"+ str(instance.slug) + str(instance.activation_key) + str(instance.activated))

    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = unique_slug_generator(instance)

pre_save.connect(rl_pre_save_receiver, sender=Profile)
```

Regards.

Comment: Which fields are being overwritten?

Comment: @AamirAdnan activation_key, slug, activated

Comment: @MasudulHasan Which values do you expect to be saved in those fields?

Comment: @cezar I set these field separately

Answer (score 0):

From the excluded fields `activation_key` and `slug` are `CharField`. They will store string values.

When you set `null=True`, then it allows `NULL` value to be saved in the database. With `blank=True` this fields are set to be optional.

It is bad practice to allow `NULL` for `CharField` i.e. `VARCHAR`. You'll have `NULL` and an empty string values `''` in the same column. It can lead to many unwanted side effects.

Let the `CharField` only with `blank=True`, if they aren't required. Django will per default save them as empty strings. So there isn't anything wrong with that.

Your problem is rather the misconception of model forms. You shouldn't redefine the model fields in the form.

For example, if `first_name` is required, then you shouldn't have `null=True, blank=True` in the model field. You can also set the widgets and the choices in the model.